# Invoking a service according to the input in a Proxy Service OSB

Tags: web-services, proxy, xquery, virtualization, osb

I have a proxy service, but according to a parameter in the request I need to invoke a different business service (e.g. if the parameter is 1 I need to invoke service A otherwise Service B), and each service has a different response, so for service A I need to transform the response but for Service B it's not necessary!

I don't know how to do this in a PS, and what is the best way using Routing or Service Call out, having into account that is for a system that will have a lot transactions. What I have in the picture is the scenario por Service 1, I need to include both scenarios

Comment: "each service has a different response" - same schema for all possible responses, right? If "yes" routing table suggestion below is fine. If "no" how about making async system with responses via jms? Or are there any specific SLA?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you can do in this case is use a [Routing Table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/dev.1111/e15866/tasks.htm#i1116533), which you would be able to set a variable somewhere earlier in your pipeline to determine which route you'll take in this table through use of an XQuery expression.